# Android run multiple launch intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

In my application, I'm trying to start multiple application activities right after each other. These are other applications on the system

For example:

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
```

If I call startActivity just for lets say "Application1" then the app will start fine, but if I call startActivity twice in a row (Once for "Applicaiton1" and again for "Application2")then it will only start the second startActivity - no errors are displayed indicating that the first startActivity failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no errors are displayed indicating that the first startActivity failed

That is because the first `startActivity()` succeeded.

`startActivity()` is asynchronous. It returns immediately, long before the activity that you requested gets started. Calling `startActivity()` twice in succession will start both of those activities, and the user will wind up seeing the second one, since that will be top-most on the task's back stack.

Most likely, the right answer is "don't do what you are trying to do". That being said, the only way to kinda sorta perhaps make it work is for you to call the first `startActivity()`, then wait until control returns to you in a future lifecycle method (e.g., `onStart()`) to invoke the second `startActivity()`.

Comment: That seems correct with seeing the top of the stack, which is what I see. However, if I press the overview button, the first application is not in the overview

Comment: @GrayShadow: By default, it will be in the same task as your app and the second application. Hence, by default, it will not show up in the overview screen.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far - is there any possible way to make it appear in the overview?

Comment: @GrayShadow: See `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK